# Workflow Triggered Action on preset interval

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, workflow-foundation

I'm relatively new to .NET workflow. I'm trying to develop an ASP.NET application that will trigger an action from the server, therefore I resort to workflow.

I have to trigger the workflow based on the configurable setting on Day of Week (e.g. Thursday but do not have time specific) while I also would need to allowed user to set the date (with time specific) they would like to trigger the workflow, on top of every Thursday.

I'm having difficulties in finding the simple solution that would put the two into the same workflow design. What is in my current thought of approach would be creating a workflow that will trigger every hours to check if there's any trigger that is set to that date and hour of time.

I would like to ask is there any other better and simple solution rather than the one that is in my thought? (Except using Windows Service)

Also, I would like to ask if I hosted this workflow on web server, will the trigger gone of by itself without any activities from user, since web server normally is stateless.

Advice are always welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for Quartz.NET http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/features.html

Probably the most popular job / task scheduling library for .NET

Should cover all your requirements.